# How to cancel file upload which uses form submit?

Tags: forms, gwt, gxt

I am using com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FormPanel; for file uploading. Code is given below:

```
FormPanel panel = new FormPanel();
file = new FileUploadField();
file.setName("uploadedfile");
file.setFieldLabel("File");

FlexTable fileTable = new FlexTable();
fileTable.setWidget(0, 0, file);
panel.add(fileTable);

Button submitButton = new Button("Save");
panel.addButton(submitButton);


submitButton.addListener(Events.Select,
new Listener<ButtonEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(ButtonEvent be) {
        panel.setAction(<someactionUrl>);
        panel.submit(); 
}
});
```

After form submit file upload gets started and i am showing a progress bar with a cancel button. When user clicks on cancel button I would like to abort the file upload (form submit request). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to cancel a form submission, you have to navigate or remove the page containing the submitting form.  To make this happen seamlessly, you have to change how you submit.

On Submit:

1. Deep clone the form element that is uploading
2. Swap the cloned input[type=file] elements for the originals.
3. Create an iframe
4. Add the iframe to the DOM
5. Append the cloned form to the iframe
6. Set the iframe's id and the form's target to a common, unique value
7. Submit the cloned form

To cancel:

1. Remove the iframe.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [gwt-upload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/). I have seen samples based on gwt-upload where in you can cancel uploading of the file.

Comment: Please add the comment when you are down voting.